# Incremental aggregation of statistics

Tags: self-study, data-mining

I need your suggestion to solve this problem:

Given a Data Warehouse with e.g. 10 million entries, additional 1000 entries arrive each day. Rather than recomputing the desired aggregates, an incremental adaptation to the new data should be supported. In order to accelerate the (re-)computation, precomputed intermediate results shall be stored and intermediate results for the new entries shall be computed. What (and how many) values suffice when considering the following aggregates? For each measure note whether it is an algebraic, holistic or distributive measure.

- mean value,
- 25% quantile of the values,
- variance

Comment: The "suggestion" is to read the definitions of algebraic, holistic, distributive... or did you expect us to answer the whole question for you?

Comment: **Please don't ask the same question twice:** [Incremental Aggregation: need some clarification](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121382/incremental-aggregation-need-some-clarification)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse to be fair the question asks for more than that, it's really a sample size question.